# Trouble overriding both ModelAdmin.save_model() and ModelForm.save()

Tags: django

I want to override a ModelForm's save() function so that it updates a field on the model if the user pressed a particular submit button. I also want to check through some other fields and update their values, and I've done this on the ModelAdmin's save_model() function. However, the save_model() function is being passed None for the object. If I comment out the form's save() function, then the save_model() function works as expected.

Is there an issue with overriding both, or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Here's a minimal example:

admin.py:

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TestForm
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        print 'test'
        super(PostAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(TestModel, TestAdmin)
```

forms.py:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        print 'test'
        super(TestForm, self).save(commit=True)
```

Comment: should the last line read TestForm instead of CategoryForm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ModelForm` needs to return the instance.

As far as I remember, just prior to `save_model`, the admin does a `save(commit=False)` and passes the unsaved instance to `save_model`. If you don't return anything, `save() == None`.

```
return super(CategoryForm, self).save(commit=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are overriding the `ModelAdmin.save_model`, and not calling the `super().save_model` (in your example you are, I can see.), you should explicitly call the `form.save()`.

If you are calling the `ModelForm.save` somehow, through super or explicit calling, I don't see why it wouldn't work; but I can tell you that if I were to override the `save_model`, my preference would be to limit myself to overriding the `Model.save()`.